# How to solve 'Error loading class com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler: javax/mail/MessagingException'?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to upload Java code to my Lambda function in AWS.
When I upload a JAR file I get an error as,

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Error loading class com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler: javax/mail/MessagingException",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"
}
```

Any idea about how to solve the same?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Lambda function that uses 3rd party jars then you have to package them in the uploaded zip file.

So in your case include the dependency by [downloading the jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) and packaging that along with your code (you don't necessarily have to do it manually, but incorporate this in the build process, e.g. generate an "uber jar" in Maven or "fat jar" in Gradle) and update the Lambda function with the new artifact

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you don't necessarily have to do it manually, but incorporate this in the build process, e.g. generate an "uber jar" in Maven or "fat jar" in Gradle - there are plugins that will automate the process.

Comment: Thanks @jannis, incorporated your comment in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Follow instructions from AWS how to create Java package.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html

You are missing javax.mail package